# Python - Saving Sum to Variable Seems to Change Value - What is Going On? - Leetcode 424. Longest Repeating Character Replacement

Tags: python, sliding-window

I have two similar versions of the same code - one that passes all tests for **Leetcode 424. Longest Repeating Character Replacement** (solved in Python) and one that does not. I need help to understand why the first version passes and the second fails.

Here is the version that passes:

```
class Solution:
    def characterReplacement(self, s: str, k: int) -> int:
        window_start, max_len = 0, 0
        char_count = defaultdict(int)
        for window_end in range(len(s)):
            new_char = s[window_end]
            char_count[new_char] += 1
            
            while len(char_count) > 1 and (window_end - window_start + 1) - max(char_count.values()) > k:
                # shrink the window
                char_count[s[window_start]] -= 1
                if char_count[s[window_start]] == 0:
                    del char_count[s[window_start]]
                window_start += 1
             # calculate the length of the window
            max_len = max(max_len, window_end - window_start + 1)
        return max_len
```

And here is the version that fails:

```
class Solution:    
    def characterReplacement(self, s: str, k: int) -> int:
        window_start, max_len = 0, 0
        char_count = defaultdict(int)
        for window_end in range(len(s)):
            new_char = s[window_end]
            char_count[new_char] += 1
            
            window_size = window_end - window_start + 1
            while len(char_count) > 1 and (window_size) - max(char_count.values()) > k:
                # shrink the window
                char_count[s[window_start]] -= 1
                if char_count[s[window_start]] == 0:
                    del char_count[s[window_start]]
                window_start += 1
            # calculate the length of the window
            max_len = max(max_len, window_end - window_start + 1)
        return max_len
```

You will notice the ONLY difference between the two is that in the failing version I save this sum to a variable: `window_end - window_start + 1` whereas in the passing version I calculate the sum in-line. What is going on? Is the act of saving this sum to a variable somehow changing its value? I am stumped.

Here are some things that I have already tried to solve the issue:

- I tried adding parentheses to make sure I didn't have the order of operations wrong but kept getting the same result.
- Initially, I was so stumped when my code wasn't working that I went line by line from my solution to one of the approved solutions on Leetcode, changing any discrepancies. I had the same logical flow as the solution. Eventually, I realized that the only difference between my code and the passing code was that I saved the sum to a variable called `window_size`. I looked up docs on subtleties of adding integers in Python, but that search yielded few results.

Comment: In the second code, `window_size` is calculated outside the while loop. So it isn't modified by the change to `window_start` on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @slothrop thank you! please feel free to add your comment as an answer, and I can then mark the issue resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that in your second piece of code, `window_size` is calculated once before the `while` loop, and never recalculated. So the determination of `(window_size) - max(char_count.values())` in the while statement always uses that initially calculated value.

The correct logic, as per the first piece of code, is for the while statement to calculate `window_end - window_start + 1` using the current value of `window_start` (which is updated on every iteration of the loop).